# ncurses window functions not working as expected

Tags: c, terminal, scheme, ncurses

I'm working on a personal experiment using s7 scheme and ncurses. I don't have a lot of experience with ncurses and I'm not able to with the tutorials I have figure out what's going wrong. When using `newwin` through a FFI interface, functions like `wprintw` or `wborder` don't work on the window I created, but the entire available terminal screen.

To start, the C example works as expected. A small window shows up and has some text in the top left corner.

```
initscr();
cbreak();
WINDOW * w = newwin(5, 15, 2, 2);
box(w, 0, 0);
wprintw(w, "ok");
wrefresh(w);
```

[image: working example]

I define functions to call from s7. It's a 1-to-1 mapping of these functions so the code should be identical. The program functions, but the window doesn't work as expected. The window size isn't correct, or it's not targetting the window pointer I give it.

```
(nc_initscr)
(nc_cbreak)
(define w (nc_newwin 5 15 2 2))
(nc_box w 0 0)
(nc_wprintw w "ok")
(nc_wrefresh w)
```

```
// Example C hook
s7_pointer _newwin(s7_scheme * sc, s7_pointer * args) {
  int height = first(args);
  int width = second(args);
  int y = third(args);
  int x = fourth(args);
  WINDOW * win = newwin(height, width, y, x);
  return s7_make_c_pointer(sc, win);
}

s7_define_function(sc, "nc_newwin", _newwin, 4, "");
```

[image]

Is there something about calling these functions that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the **`(define w (nc_newwin 5 15 2 2))`** is not passing the window-pointer as expected, or the other hooks are ignoring that.  Either way, they are using **`stdscr`** rather than the value returned by **`newwin`**.

Comment: I checked the pointer addresses of the window I'm passing and `stdscr`. `w` is not null and they have different addresses. I've also tried declaring the window that gets created from this call as a global variable, and then using that variable for future calls to `wprintw`. Same result.

Comment: `box` is using `stdscr`, however.

Comment: I don't know why. `w` isn't equal to `stdscr`, and the hook functions get the correct address. The behavior is the same using `wborder`.

Comment: I can't edit my comment anymore, but to be sure I've run it through GDB and checked:
`(gdb) print stdscr ->$1 = (WINDOW *) 0x555555843290`, `(gdb) print win -> $2 = (WINDOW *) 0x55555586cdf0`

Comment: Refer to the [source](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/a1103108be6ef58d087f33755efd11939da42109/ncurses/base/lib_box.c#L63).

Comment: I'll see if I can manually include ncurses to debug it, though think it'll take some time to respond.

Comment: Error was on my part when casting arguments. The `win` pointer was fine, the integer arguments got garbled on converting and sent trash to the function that defaulted to the available terminal size.

Answer (score 0):

Was an error on my part. I was reading the scheme integer arguments incorrectly. The invalid values were being defaulted to the same size as `stdscr`.